# 2D Ring modulated by a cosine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to make an image of a ring of inner radius `r1` and outter radius `r2` with values modulated by a cosinus.
I've already made this and tried several options (comments in the code) :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def circle(x_center,y_center,r):
        
    
    # theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 500)    

    # x = r*np.cos(theta) - x_center
    # y = r*np.sin(theta) - y_center            

    xv = np.linspace(-r-1,r+1,500) 

    X,Y = np.meshgrid(xv, xv)
    profilegrid = np.ones(X.shape, float)
    for i, a in enumerate(X[0, :]):
        for k, z in enumerate(Y[:, 0]):
            theta = np.arctan(z/a) 
            current_radius = np.sqrt(a**2 + z**2)
            cond1 = current_radius <= r
            # cond2 = np.logical_and(np.abs(theta)>=0,np.abs(theta)<=pi)
            cond2 = a==a

            if np.logical_and(cond1,cond2)==False :
                profilegrid[i, k] = 0
            else : 
                profilegrid[i, k] = np.cos(theta)

    return xv,profilegrid

xv1,circle_big = circle(0,0,1)
xv2,circle_small = circle(0,0,0.5)

new = circle_big - circle_small
plt.imshow(new, interpolation="bicubic", 
            origin="lower", extent=[min(xv1),max(xv1),min(xv1),max(xv1)])
plt.colorbar()


plt.show()
```

But the output image gives me :

[image: 1]

I should have values between `-1` and `1` and not between `0` and `1`. Furthermore, as you can see I've asked a circle of radius `r1=1` substracted to a circle of radius `r2=0.5` in order to simulate the ring but the circle seems to be a little bit bigger.

Any idea about the origin of those issues?

EDIT :

Found the issue concerning the radius problem thanks to @tgrtim :

`xv = np.linspace(-r-1,r+1,500)` should be fixed and replaced by :

```
xv = np.linspace(-2,2,500)
```

Furthermore the problem of the values interval `[0:1]` instead of `[-1:1]` comes from the `arctan` boundaries. So do you have any idea how to change this in order to have only one maximum and no mirror pattern like this?

Comment: Arctan would only provide values between +/- pi/2 so cos(x) would be limited between 0 and 1. Without looking into it too much I'd assume the size difference is something to do with the different xv values you use for the two circles.

Comment: @tgrtim Yes you're right ! I've changed xv values in order to let them fixed for any circle generation. And now the problem is fixed. Now the issue concerning the cosine still stays on. I see the problem but how can i solve this issue ? I don't want to have a mirror pattern like this but more like something between -1 and 1. Any idea? Cheers

Comment: Problem solved using the function 
math.atan2(y,x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for the mirror pattern can be resolved involving the function `math.atan2(y,x)` instead of `np.arctan(y/x)`.

[image]